# Metric space limit points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $A\subseteq X$, with a limit point, x.

Pick $x_1 \in B(x,\frac{1}{2}) \cap A$

Pick $x_2\in B(x,\frac{1}{2^2})\cap A$. Such that $x_1\neq x_2$.

Pick $x_3\in B(x,\frac{1}{2^3}) \cap A$ such that $x_3\neq x_2\neq x_2$.
..
I was wondering why such $x_i's$ exist? How can we be sure that $x_i \neq x_j$ for all $i\neq j$ exist?

Let me elaborate: It doesn't seem to me the above holds. What does seem to hold is if: We
Picked $x_1\in B(x,\frac{1}{2}) \cap A$ that is not $x$. Pick $x_2\in B(x,min(\frac{1}{2^2},d(x,x_1) ))\cap A$. Pick $x_3\in B(x,min(\frac{1}{2^3},d(x,x_1),d(x,x_2))) \cap A$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure by choosing in $x_2$ in $B(x,\min(\frac{1}{2^2}, d(x_1,x)))$ (and also in $A$ and unequal to $x$). Then it is in $B(x,\frac{1}{2^2})$ a fortiori and as $d(x_2,x) < d(x_1,x)$ we know $x_1 \neq x_2$.

After choosing $n$ distinct points all $\neq x$, define $r_{n+1} = \min(d(x,x_i): i \le n)$ which is $>0$ and pick $x_{n+1} \in A \cap B(x, \min(r_{n+1}, \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}))$ (which can be done as $x$ is a limit point of $A$) then $d(x_{n+1},x) < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and also $d(x_{n+1},x) < r_{n+1}$ which implies it is different from all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Minor subtlety: in order to ensure that all $x_i$ are mutually different, it's enough to ensure in the recursion that the new $x_{n+1}$ is different from $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ at every stage $n$.

I already sketched this construction in an [earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3552218/4280), did you forget about it? You do mention it in the post..

Comment: No no, I didn't forget this time, I used it to construct the sequence with the minimums. But, I wrote my question without really thinking first. Ofcourse $B(x, min(\frac{1}{2^i},.....,d(x,x_{n-1}))$ is contained in $B(x,\frac{1}{2^i})$

Comment: @topologicalmagician At every stage you can get a point as close as you need at that point, the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ are not essential, we could also take $\frac{1}{n}$; that also ensures $x_n \to x$. I started to write my answer before your edit that used the min-idea.

Comment: @topologicalmagician note that this argument can be made to work in any first countable $T_1$ space. To keep distinctness we really use that finite sets are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $x $ is a limit point  of $A $, for each(!)  $r>0$ the set $B (x,r) \cap A $ is not empty.

Comment: I know. But how can we guarantee that every point we choose is distinct from the other?? All that tells us is that $B(x,r) \cap A\backslash$ $\{$ x$\}$ is non-empty. It doesn't tell us that each point we pick is distinct from the other! All it tells us is that every point we pick is different from x.

Answer (score 0):

Its because $x$ is a limit point. If $d(x,x_1)=r_1$, then you can pick $x_2$ with $d(x,x_2)<r_1$. Since $x$ is a limit point such an $x_2$ exists. Can you see how to obtain infinitely many points close to $x$ with this process?

Comment: Yes. I posted an elaboration though.

Comment: If $x_2$ is in $B(x,\text{min}(1/2^2,d(x,x_1)))$, then surely $x_2\in B(x,1/2^2)$